# Nonsingularity of sum of matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices

Consider the matrix $E$ where $E$ is defined as follows:

$E=A+\gamma BC+DB-BC^{-1}DC$

where $\gamma$>0, $A,C$ are positive definite, $D$ is Hurwitz and $B$ is positive semidefinite. I have a conjecture that $E$ is nonsingular. Am I correct? One way I was trying to approach the problem is to explore the eigenvalues of $E$. Any counter-examples which can disprove the conjecture might be enough if the conjecture is not true.

I was trying to start as follows. We know that $\lambda(XZ)=\lambda(ZX)$ where $\lambda(.)$ denotes the eigenvalue of $(.)$. Using this result, we can conclude that $\lambda(C^{-1}DC)=\lambda(CC^{-1}D)=\lambda(D)$ and somehow proceed from here. However I am not able to figure out a way to move from here.

Comment: The following might be a counter example : Fix $A$ positive definite, let $B$ be the positive definite square root of $A$ i.e. $A=B\times B$, let $C=B$, $D=-B$ and $\gamma=1$. I am not completly clear on the definition of Hurwitz but according wikipedia, a negative definite matrix should do.

Comment: With the above substitution, $E=2B^2$ which is nonsingular. Please can you recheck your substitution.

Comment: What's the motivation behind this conjecture?

Comment: I am working on a noncovex optimization problem. I transformed it to a convex problem. It turns out to show that the duality gap is zero it is enough to show that $E$ is nonsingular